# Forcing NonLinearModelFit to be positive

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I've used the `NonLinearModelFit` function to get the fit for my data. I require the fit to to go through `(0,0)` (which I have succeeded in doing), however, I also need the fit to be positive, which I am yet to manage.

An example of my data:

```
mydata = {{0.700017, 0.2029}, {1.06981, 0.2028}, {1.17239, 0.4867},  {0.956762, 0.2104}, {1.48915, 0.45609}, {1.4274, 0.45039}, {1.4904, 0.5719}, {1.76748, 1.04605}, {1.57645, 1.06265}, , {1.866, 1.335}, {1.87094, 1.6095}, {1.96465, 1.8551}, {2.43712, 2.3769}, {2.63941, 3.771}, {2.76015, 4.133}}
```

This is how I fit the data currently:

```
modelquad = c x + a x^2;

QuadFit20 = NonlinearModelFit[mydata, {modelquad, (modelquad /. x -> 0) == 0}, {a, c}, x]
```

Which gives me a lovely fit, passing through `(0,0)`, but does dip below y = 0. Is there any way of forcing the fit to be positive for all y values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include **minimal** example of data that demonstrates the problem that you are having.

Comment: Sorry, example added!

Comment: Why not use `Max[0, c x + a x^2]` for your model as you have only 1 data point where the prediction is less than 0 with the original model `c x + a x^2`.  Also, just including an intercept will also fix the problem.  If your original model without an intercept is a theoretical model, then that means you have data issues.

Answer (score 5):

```
nlmf = NonlinearModelFit[mydata, {c x + a x^2, c >= 0}, {a, c}, x]
```

This constraint $c \ge 0$ comes from analyzing the derivative of the model: $df/dx = c + 2 a x$. If at (0,0) the model must remain non-negative, then this derivative must be non-negative as well. Thus, $c$ must be greater than or equal to 0.

There is no need to specify that the fit is 0 at $x=0$ as currently written, as that is required by the model's form.

Note also that as $c$ ends up being quite small, it is possible eliminate it from the model entirely and just fit $a x^2$ to the data. This can be done in `LinearModelFit` which provides a larger bank of statistics than `NonlinearModelFit` if those are of interest:

```
lmf = LinearModelFit[mydata, {x^2}, x, IncludeConstantBasis->False]
```

Comment: This does give positive values for $x>0$ but at the expense of a horrible fit.